# What is this round thing on the pantry door in The Shining

Tags: props, the-shining

When Wendy locks Jack in the pantry, there is a round object on the door.
[image: Shot]

I thought that it was something to help out if someone gets trapped in the pantry, but based on the scene, it seems like that's not the case.

What is this object?

Comment: Could it be a ..doorknob?

Comment: @Joachim I'd have to watch again to see the outside, but I am pretty sure that you could just push the door open.

Comment: This photo is almost as good a canonical Jack Nicholson photo as "Heeeere's Jack!"  Wonder why we don't see it too often?

Comment: @davidbak - "Johnny" - he was imitating [Ed McMahon introducing Johnny Carson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZKmsA8bzao).

Comment: @HannoverFist yes but "here's jack" works with a google image search just as well .. as it turns out ...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's a commercial walk-in refrigerator door handle, known as a 'push-strike'

Basically it just pushes through the door onto the regular latch on the outside so you can get out... unless in this case someone has locked it from the outside. You can bump it with your butt if your hands are full.

[image]

*Late edit:* I found a shot of both sides of the door from the movie...

[image]